# How to properly merge a variable by group from another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have two datasets- one is a baseline and the other is a follow up dataset.

DF1 is the baseline (cross-sectional) data with id, date, score1, score2, level, and grade.
DF2 has id, date, score1, and score2, in a long format with multiple rows per id.

```
 df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(id = c(1,2,3),
                 date = c("2020-06-03","2020-07-02","2020-06-11"),
                 score1 =c(6,8,5),
                 score2=c(1,1,6),
                 baselevel=c(2,2,2),
                 basegrade=c("B","B","A")))

 df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(id =c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                  date = c("2020-06-10","2020-06-17","2020-06-24",
                  "2020-07-01", "2020-07-03", "2020-07-10","2020-07-17", "2020-06-14",
                  "2020-06-22", "2020-06-29"),
                  score1 = c(3,1,7,8,8,6,5,5,3,5),
                  score2 = c(1,4,5,4,1,1,2,6,7,1)) )
```

This is what I want as a result of merging the two dfs.

```
 id      date      score1  score 2  baselevel   basegrade
 1    2020-06-03    6       1         2           "B"
 1    2020-06-10    3       1         2           "B"
 1    2020-06-17    1       4         2           "B"
 1    2020-06-24    7       5         2           "B"
 1    2020-07-01    8       4         2           "B"
 2    2020-07-02    8       1         2           "B"
 2    2020-07-03    8       1         2           "B"
 2    2020-07-10    6       1         2           "B"
 2    2020-07-17    5       2         2           "B"
 3    2020-06-11    5       6         1           "A"  
 3    2020-06-14    5       6         1           "A" 
 3    2020-06-22    3       7         1           "A" 
 3    2020-06-29    5       1         1           "A"
```

I tried two different code below using merge, but I still get NAs.. what am I missing here?
Any help would be appreciated!!

```
dfcombined1 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("id","date"), all= TRUE)
dfcombined2 <- merge(df1, df2, by=intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), all= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind_rows()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(starts_with("base"), .direction = "updown") %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = T)

# # A tibble: 13 x 6
# # Groups:   id [3]
#    id    date       score1 score2 baselevel basegrade
#    <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    
#  1 1     2020-06-03 6      1      2         B        
#  2 1     2020-06-10 3      1      2         B        
#  3 1     2020-06-17 1      4      2         B        
#  4 1     2020-06-24 7      5      2         B        
#  5 1     2020-07-01 8      4      2         B        
#  6 2     2020-07-02 8      1      2         B        
#  7 2     2020-07-03 8      1      2         B        
#  8 2     2020-07-10 6      1      2         B        
#  9 2     2020-07-17 5      2      2         B        
# 10 3     2020-06-11 5      6      2         A        
# 11 3     2020-06-14 5      6      2         A        
# 12 3     2020-06-22 3      7      2         A        
# 13 3     2020-06-29 5      1      2         A
```

Comment: Hm I have dplyr loaded but when i run rows_insert i get an error: could not find function "rows_insert"

Comment: @JNB `rows_insert()` is one of new functions in `dplyr 1.0.0`. You need to update the package version.

Comment: @JNB I found `bind_rows()` is ok. Doesn't need to use `rows_insert()`. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df1 %>% bind_rows(df2) %>% arrange(id) %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(baselevel) %>% fill(basegrade)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 6
# Groups:   id [3]
   id    date       score1 score2 baselevel basegrade
   <fct> <fct>      <fct>  <fct>  <fct>     <fct>    
 1 1     2020-06-03 6      1      2         B        
 2 1     2020-06-10 3      1      2         B        
 3 1     2020-06-17 1      4      2         B        
 4 1     2020-06-24 7      5      2         B        
 5 1     2020-07-01 8      4      2         B        
 6 2     2020-07-02 8      1      2         B        
 7 2     2020-07-03 8      1      2         B        
 8 2     2020-07-10 6      1      2         B        
 9 2     2020-07-17 5      2      2         B        
10 3     2020-06-11 5      6      2         A        
11 3     2020-06-14 5      6      2         A        
12 3     2020-06-22 3      7      2         A        
13 3     2020-06-29 5      1      2         A
```

Answer (score 0):

A double `merge` maybe.

```
merge(merge(df1[-(3:4)], df2, all.y=TRUE)[-(3:4)], df1[-(2:4)], all.x=TRUE)
#    id       date score1 score2 baselevel basegrade
# 1   1 2020-06-10      3      1         2         B
# 2   1 2020-06-17      1      4         2         B
# 3   1 2020-06-24      7      5         2         B
# 4   1 2020-07-01      8      4         2         B
# 5   2 2020-07-03      8      1         2         B
# 6   2 2020-07-10      6      1         2         B
# 7   2 2020-07-17      5      2         2         B
# 8   3 2020-06-14      5      6         2         A
# 9   3 2020-06-22      3      7         2         A
# 10  3 2020-06-29      5      1         2         A
```